# Primal number task

Tags: python, numbers, task, helper

Hi I have task that that I dont know how to do. Basically I need to write primal numberswhere is only difference by 2 numbers, only primal number which is either two more or two less than another prime number and then print every pair of these primes that are less than or equal to 100.
Here is how it should look like.

3 5

5 7

11 13

17 19

29 31

41 43

59 61

71 73

Here is my code.I don't know how to eliminate these that are more than 2

```
for b in range(1, n):      
  if b>2:                    
      for p in range(2, b):  
         if (b%p) ==0:
          break
      else: 
        print(b )
```

Comment: These are called "twin primes".

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your existing code, you could do:

```py
    lastprime = 2
    for b in range(1, n):      
      if b>2:                    
          for p in range(2, b):  
             if (b%p) ==0:
              break
          else:
            if b == lastprime + 2:
                print(lastprime, b)
            lastprime = b
```

Comment: I don't get that last part that you wrote can you explain it tome I woul be grateful. I know tha t I need to define 2 but I don't understand this                                                                   
          if b == lastprime + 2:
                print(lastprime, b)
            lastprime = b

Comment: @DanielM_D It might be helpful to just walk through the code, starting with `b = 1`, step through it line by line and keep track of what the values of the variables are, like on a piece of paper.

Comment: Generally, this solution works like this:
For each number from 1 to n you check if this number is a prime number (here you did this, by checking if any of the previous numbers can be divided by the current number).
But need to check pairs, right? So if b is the current prime number then you need previous one or next one to compare if it is larger or smaller by 2 (this is done in if `b == lastprime + 2`). To get access to the previous one you can save the current one, so in the next iteration it becomes the previous one (this is done in `lastprime = b`)

Comment: @Domino Thanks I finally get it so I need to define  2 or any number except 1 I try  other 
 numbers and it works same. Then I will save to b any number except 1 that I defined and then add+2 because I need next primal number that is larger by 2 and to get previous I need to just save the current one and in the next iretation it becomes previous one. Its just  conversely without adding +2    .

Answer (score 0):

It should be a bit more efficient by using Sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
sieve = [True for _ in range(n + 1)]
current_number = 2
while (current_number * current_number <= n):
    if (sieve[current_number] == True):
        for i in range(current_number * current_number, n + 1, current_number):
            sieve[i] = False
    current_number += 1

primes = [index for index in range(2, n + 1) if sieve[index]]
for i in range(len(primes) - 1):
    first = primes[i]
    second = primes[i + 1]
    if first + 2 == second:
        print(f'{first} {second}')
```

or even more efficient:

```
sieve = [False] * 2 + [True] * (n - 1)
for number in range(int(n ** 0.5 + 1.5)):
    if sieve[number]:
        for i in range(number * number, n + 1, number):
            sieve[i] = False
primes = [i for i, prime in enumerate(sieve) if prime]
for i, first in enumerate(primes[:-1]):
    second = primes[i + 1]
    if first + 2 == second:
        print(f'{first} {second}')
```

Explanation:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/

Comment: thanks but we need to use only need to use loops. That guy what he wrote works but I don't get it why is there 2+2. When I tried it doesnt matter how you define it will show the same but still dont get it